# Entity Framework code first get group by data to list of object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to use Entity Framework code first to get group by data then add to `List<object>` ?

My code does not seem work:

```
public IEnumerable<Data> getData()
{
    List<Data> data_cont = new List<Data>();

    DataContent db = new DataContent();

    // not working code 
    data_cont = db.MyData.GroupBy(f => f.start_station_num).ToList();

    return data_cont;
}
```

Why does `.GroupBy` not work the same as `.Where` like this

```
// working code
data_cont = db.MyData.Where(x => x.start_station_num == "\"31232\"").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that code doesn't "work" (ie....it won't even build) is because the GroupBy method returns

`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` and not an

`IEnumerable<TElement>` like the 
Where method does.

You need to change your variable declaration for data_cont.   It should look like this:

```
List<IGrouping<string, Data>> data_cont = null;
```

Instead of using List like this:

```
List<Data> data_cont = new List<Data>();
```